# consider first match only for regex and ignore the last match

Tags: regex

I have input string as below.

> created_at : 2017-02-16 13:22:16,
>
> created_at : 2017-02-16 13 : 22:16,

What I wanted is to get double quotes for `created_at` & to do same, I have  regex as `\b(.*\s)(:\s)`

Now to format I use substituion as `"$1" $2`

Below is the output I get

> "created_at " : 2017-02-16 13:22:16,
>
> "created_at : 2017-02-16 13 " : 22:16,

The problem I have is for second line the double quote get shifted after 13. What I wanted to do is regex will always consider first match and not the last match so that second line output would be same as first.

Is there way to get this done using regex?

### Find below link for demo

https://regex101.com/r/94nGZb/1

Comment: You could make your first match non-greeedy. Something like `(.*?)( :.*)` should do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

According to your updated request in the comments, here something that will also match your single line case:

```
(.*?)\s?(:.*?)(\\n\\n|$)
```

and can be seen here:
https://regex101.com/r/zjQAL2/4

---

You can change it to begin from the start of string and be multiline like this:

```
/^(.*?)\s?(:.*)$/gm
```

See it in action:

https://regex101.com/r/zjQAL2/1

Comment: what if I have all string as 1 string? e.g. `created_at : 2017-02-16 13:22:16,\n\ncreated_at : 2017-02-16 13 : 22:16,\n\nlevel : 1,`